# Edit lines in between cells?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Check the pic attached in the link. The line in between the first two cells is indented, but the line in between the bottom two cells goes all the way across. The first two cells are a separate section than the bottom cell (so there are 2 sections, the previous coder set it up that way and that's how it has to be...). I am trying to get the line in between the bottom two cells the same way the line between the first two are (indented). What would be the best way to do this? Pic is attached

here is the cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"InAppPurchaseViewCellIdentifer";
    //    InAppPurchaseViewCell *cell = (InAppPurchaseViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    InAppPurchaseViewCell *cell = (InAppPurchaseViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    NSArray *currentSectionArray = nil;

    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0:
            currentSectionArray = _productGroupZeroArray;
            break;
        case 1:
            currentSectionArray = _productGroupOneArray;
            break;
        case 2:
            currentSectionArray = _productGroupTwoArray;
            break;
        case 3:
            currentSectionArray = _productGroupThreeArray;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    NSDictionary *currentProductDictionary = [currentSectionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *currentProductIdString = [currentProductDictionary objectForKey:kInAppOptionProductID];

    __block SKProduct *currentProduct = nil;

    [_skProductArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(SKProduct *product, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        if ([product.productIdentifier isEqualToString:currentProductIdString]) {
            currentProduct = product;
            *stop = YES;
        }
    }];

    if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
        cell.productNameLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor];
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor];
        cell.productNameLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
        cell.priceLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:249.0/255.0 green:198.0/255.0 blue:6.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
        cell.priceLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    } else {
        cell.productNameLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor];
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor];
        cell.productNameLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
        cell.priceLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:249.0/255.0 green:198.0/255.0 blue:6.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
        cell.priceLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }

    cell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    if ([[InAppPurchaseHelper sharedInstance] productPurchased:currentProduct.productIdentifier]) {
        if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
            cell.priceLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.576 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];
        } else {
            cell.priceLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.576 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];
        }
        cell.priceLabel.text = @"Paid";
        cell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    } else {
        [_priceFormatter setLocale:currentProduct.priceLocale];
        NSString *priceString = [_priceFormatter stringFromNumber:currentProduct.price];
        cell.priceLabel.text = priceString;
    }

    cell.frame = CGRectOffset(cell.frame, 10, 10);

    if (currentSectionArray == _productGroupZeroArray) {
        cell.productNameLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }else if (currentSectionArray == _productGroupOneArray) {
        cell.productNameLabel.text = @"Annual Subscription:\nTestBank for every exam!";
    }

    return cell;
}
```

[image]

Comment: add some code of the table.

Comment: Best way is do your own separator with a UIView of height 1... fully customizable... (so u can hide last separator also)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
[tableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(spaceValue, 0, 0, 0)];
```

Hope this could help.

Comment: yes, that could be nice. After you inited the `tableview`.

Comment: I used it in viewDidLoad but it didn't change anything :/

Answer (score 0):

The *tableView* separator **between** sections is different from the *cell* separator within a section.

You can

- change the first cell's separator inset to match the section
  separator, or
- update the code to group all the cells in the *same*
  section.

I understand that you don't wish to do either one, but this works within what Apple supports.  Otherwise, you may have to hide Apple's separator and draw your own.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
// Remove seperator inset
if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
       [cell setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
}

// Prevent the cell from inheriting the Table View's margin settings
if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setPreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins:)]) {
    [cell setPreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins:NO];
}

// Explictly set your cell's layout margins
if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
    [cell setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
}}
```

Hope it can help you.